# Replacing HTML markup characters with the coreesponding character entity reference

Tags: html, character

Recently when I was developing a simple web site i came across a problem with replacing HTML mark up(eg- & , '', "", % etc).
Most of the time we have to replace these mark up with the corresponding character entity reference. but the thing I can't figure out is at some instances I didn't have to replace the mark up with it's corresponding character entity reference (e.g- $ -> &amp;)

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape any of the characters, providing you can type it on your keyboard, and the tools used to edit and display the HTML files don't destroy them (because they aren't Unicode compatible for example). However with many characters it's easier to, say, type &emdash; than try and work out how to type it.

Answer (score 0):

The special characters in reference SGML (hence HTML) are (as far as you need to know) `>`, `<` and `&`. If you start with real-world text that you want to include in your mark-up, you have to replace precisely all of those by their entity or character references (`&lt;` etc.) and you will be fine. (Exceptions are if you are inside an CDATA marked section or an element with content type CDATA, but let us just assume that that's never the case.)